# Add or remove paragraphs like blocks or sections with custom name

Tags: pdftex, letters

I am totally new to latex.

For cover letter in latex, I want to divide my one page content in 4 paragraphs. This body part keeps on changing based on requirements. there are in all 9 paragraphs that could occupy this 4 parts of body.

What i want to do is, name this sections with some names or any other methodology so that when i want to create the document i can simply add,

`\begin{document}
\textblock2 
\textblock5 
\textblock7 
\textblock9 
\end{document}`

and similarly just any combination i wish.

Current enviornment setup have

`\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
 \moderncvstyle{banking} 
moderncv.cls version : %% Copyright 2006-2015 Xavier Danaux (****@gmail.com).`

OS: macOSX El Capitan, TexMaker (open source editor) - performing Quick Build with default settings ( I mean i have not changed anything).

Its a little bit urgent requirement. Please, guide me. Do let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example with just three paragraphs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\texton{First possible paragraph}
\def\texttw{Second possible paragraph}
\def\textth{Third possible paragraph}

\begin{document}

\section{Whatever}

\texttw\par
\texton\par
\textth\par
\texttw
\end{document}
```

Just define you paragraphs with `\def` before `\begin{document}`. In the main document use `\par` or leave a blank line between any two paragraphs.

[image]

Comment: seems wasted a lot of time on this. Thanks. Quick question: to make it more clean is it possible to put those things in separate files  and not in the main file ? @summer

Comment: Note that you cannot use numbers in the names you give to the paragraphs, e.g. you can use `\def\texton{...}` but not `\def\text1{...}`

Comment: `\input` seems to be the answer.